# How to wait for function's promise in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise

In my Node.js app I have a function that loops over an array of URLs and get their values, once loop is done it will return the final value as a Map. Code following.

```
let getResults = function(urls){
    let results = new Map();
    let retrievePromises = [];
    urls.forEach(function (value, i) {
        retrievePromises.push(
            restAgent.get(value).then(function(data){
                for (let item of data.items) {
                    let name = item.filter(n => n.name === "somename"); //filter array
                    let obj = {};
                    obj.name = item.name;
                    obj.address = item.address;
                    results.set(name, obj);
                }

            }).catch(function(err){
                console.log(err);
            })
        );
    });

    Promise.all(retrievePromises).then(function(){
        return this.results;
    });
}
```

If then I run, `console.log(getResults());` it will return `undefined` as it is triggered before the function returns results.
How to solve this issue, and *since I am new to Promises*, any possible improvements to the code? (I know that forEach is not favorable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to return the `Promise`. In your case you will have to return the `return Promise.all`

```
let getResults = function(urls){
    let results = new Map();
    let retrievePromises = [];
    urls.forEach(function (value, i) {
        retrievePromises.push(
            restAgent.get(value).then(function(data){
                for (let item of data.items) {
                    let name = item.filter(n => n.name === "somename"); //filter array
                    let obj = {};
                    obj.name = item.name;
                    obj.address = item.address;
                    results.set(name, obj);
                }

            }).catch(function(err){
                console.log(err);
            })
        );
    });

    return Promise.all(retrievePromises).then(function(){
        return results;
    });
}
```

There is no need for improvements, you code code is optimal. Good job!

To check the results you will have to do `.then()` when you call `getResults()`. If you do `console.log(getResults());` you will get the promise object.

To see the result you have to do

```
getResults(urls).then(function(results){
    console.log(results);
})
```

Comment: Also has to use `then()` when calling this function

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @charlietfl I added it to my answer.

Comment: Since this was selected as correct , I assume it is working . I wasn't sure about what this in  this.results point to ? I thought it would point to the function in the then in Promise.all